# en la codificación ¿Qué significa una "secuencia arbitraria"?

Tags: email, codificación, base64

Estoy intentando entender lo que es la codificación base64 que utilizan los servicios SOAP para transferencia de bits a través de `XML`, dentro de XML esta codificación se llama binaryBase64. En PHP existe una función que códifica a base64, se llama base64_encode(), y no se si es lo mismo el tipo `XML` binaryBase64 que el resultado que arroja base64_encode() y es lo que estoy intentando entender.

En la Wikipedia encontre en la definición de su precursor **Protocolo Privacy-Enhanced Electronic Mail (PEM)**, esta dice que **PEM define un esquema de caracteres imprimibles que usa Base 64 para transformar una secuencia arbitraria de octetos en un formato**, pero no entiendo  ¿Que que es una "secuencia arbitraria"?.

En unos fragmentos gratuitos del libro "Servicios avanzados de telecomunicación", encontré que en las cabecera de un mensaje de correo se le puede indicar que el cuerpo del mensaje esta codificado en binario (o algo así no me adentre mucho en la lectura es un poco extensa para el propósito).

--binary: Los datos no han sido codificados y consisten en un **flujo de de datos binario arbitrario**.

Y salió otra vez el término ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que significa?

Comment: Una secuencia cualquiera, aleatoria. Da igual la que sea.

Answer (score 1):

Una secuencia de datos arbitraria significa en esencia que está compuesta de bytes y que esos bytes pueden tener cualquier valor posible entre 00000000 y 11111111 (binario), o si prefieres escribirlo en hexadecimal, entre 00 y FF (o si prefieres en decimal, entre 0 y 255).

Estas secuencias de bytes "arbitrarias" plantean problemas en los protocolos orientados a texto. En estos protocolos se espera que la secuencia de bytes no tome cualquier valor posible, sino solo valores entre 00000000 y 01111111 (o 00-7F), pues esos valores son los que cubre el estándar ASCII. Es más, a menudo se eliminan de ese rango los caracteres "no imprimibles" que corresponden a códigos de control, por lo que el rango se reduce a 20-7F (hexadecimal).

Los protocolos orientados a texto (como SMTP) por tanto no admiten una secuencia *arbitraria*, sino una secuencia ASCII. ¿Qué pasa entonces cuando queremos enviar por uno de estos protocolos un byte que se sale del rango permitido? O más genéricamente aún, si queremos enviar una *secuencia arbitraria* (o sea, cualquier byte sin preocuparme de si entra o no entra en lo permitido por ASCII).

Pues Base64 es una codificación diseñada para eso. Toma como entrada una secuencia de bytes arbitraria y genera como resultado otra secuencia de bytes que tiene la misma información, pero recodificada de modo que sólo use ciertos caracteres: letras mayúsculas entre A y Z, letras minúsculas entre a y z, dígitos de 0 a 9, y los signos "+" y "/" (junto con el signo "=" para un relleno opcional). Todos esos caracteres se pueden codificar en ASCII y entran en el rango 20-7F, por lo que no plantean ya ningún problema al protocolo basado en texto que los tenga que transportar.

Una vez esa secuencia Base64 ha llegado a su destino, su codificación se deshace para recuperar la secuencia de bytes original.

Como ves, el objetivo es conseguir hacer pasar una secuencia de bytes cualquiera a través de un medio de transmisión que permite solo secuencias de bytes que representen texto ASCII.

### Un ejemplo

Quiero transmitir el emoji , el cual obviamente no es ASCII.

Lo primero será convertirlo en una secuencia de bytes. Para eso existe un estándar como UTF-8. El código de ese emoji en UTF-8 se compone de los bytes siguientes:

```
11110000
10011111
10011000
10000010
```

O, si prefieres, en hexadecimal: `f0 9f 98 82`

De esos bytes ninguno es ASCII (ninguno está en el rango 20-7F), por lo que transmitirlo por un protocolo orientado a texto que imponga esa limitación sería a priori imposible.

Pero entonces usamos Base64 y la secuencia de bytes arbitraria se convierte en la cadena:

```
8J+Ygg==
```

Y eso ya son todo caracteres ASCII válidos que se pueden enviar por cualquier protocolo.

Una vez recibidos, el método `decode()` de Base64 te devolvería la secuencia de bytes original, la cual interpretada como UTF-8 te permitirá recuperar el emoji